# Android spinner dropdown height not wrapping to content

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have created a spinner with a dropdown and i am using a custom array adapter to populate the dropdown.
For some reason the dropdown height occupies entire screen. Even if the dropdown has only 2 rows.

I have tried setting. But no use. Any idea why?

```xml
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner"
    android:dropDownWidth="618dp"
    android:dropDownHeight="468dp"
</Spinner>
```

Edit: I found the problem. It's because sample_dialog is a relative layout. If I change it to a linear layout it works fine. But why can't I use a relative layout?

```java
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_dialog, null);
}
```

Comment: Is this in a vertical `LinearLayout`? Please post the rest of your xml

Comment: Do post your screenshot along with your whole layout code.

Comment: It is in a horizontal linear layout

Answer (score 1):

Use my function in your activity:

**dimens.xml:**

```
<dimen name="my_dimen">140dp</dimen>
```

**My_Activity:**

```
    private void SpinnerHeight(Spinner spinner) {
        try {
            Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            popup.setAccessible(true);

            // Get private mPopup member variable and try cast to ListPopupWindow
            android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow) popup.get(spinner);

            // Set popupWindow height to 140dp


            int altoSpinner = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.my_dimen);
                popupWindow.setHeight(altoSpinner);


        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // silently fail...
        }
    }

My_spinner.setAdapter(adapterData);

SpinnerHeight(My_spinner);
```